# Check for a value in cells and compare it to a singular cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to look for a name in my sheets and once it is found a random number will be generated. However, I can't seem to match up the names.

What shows up when i run a `Logger.log` is `[VALUE,,,]` and I'm trying to compare that to `VALUE` but it doesn't work. Any help?

Code:

```
var num = Math.floor(1000+Math.random()*9000);
num = parseInt(num).toFixed();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

for(i = 7; i<=10; i++)
{
  var value = ss[7].getRange("C10:G20").getValues();
  if(c == value[0])
    return num;
}
```

Comment: As stated in the Spreadsheet Service documentation, `Range#getValues` returns an `Array` of `Arrays`. Inside the inner `Array` is each value. Essentially, getValues() returns an array of row data. Each row data is an array of column values. PS: you probably also wanted to use `ss[i]` and not `ss[7]`.

Comment: So does that mean I can't compare a single value to an array?

Comment: no, it means you have to be sure you're comparing similar things. Read about comparisons in JavaScript.